# Why are case objects serializable and case classes not?

Tags: serialization, scala, case-class, remote-actors

I am playing with this example http://scala.sygneca.com/code/remoteactors to learn how remote actors work in Scala (2.8.0). In particular I slightly modified how the messages send by the actors are defined as it follows:

```
sealed trait Event extends Serializable
case object Ping extends Event
case object Pong extends Event
case object Quit extends Event
```

and everything works as expected. Unfortunately if I define the events as case classes instead of case objects as in:

```
sealed trait Event extends Serializable
case class Ping extends Event
case class Pong extends Event
case class Quit extends Event
```

my example stop working. In more detail it seems that while case objects are serializable, case classes aren't. Indeed when I try to run my example with this last modification I get the following exception:

```
scala.actors.remote.DelegateActor@148cc8c: caught java.io.NotSerializableException: scalachat.remote.Ping$
java.io.NotSerializableException: scalachat.remote.Ping$
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
    at scala.actors.remote.JavaSerializer.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at scala.actors.remote.NetKernel.namedSend(NetKernel.scala:38)
    at scala.actors.remote.NetKernel.forward(NetKernel.scala:71)
    at scala.actors.remote.DelegateActor$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Proxy.scala:182)
    at scala.actors.remote.DelegateActor$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Proxy.scala:123)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:34)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.compute(ReactorTask.scala:66)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:147)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

Is there a reason why case objects can be made serializable and case classes can't? Is there a way to make my example working with case classes either?

Edit: as suggested by Victor and confirmed by Aaron I am sending the companion object as message instead of the class. Moreover inspecting the compiled code with javap it appears evident that while the class is serializable:

```
public class scalachat.remote.Ping extends java.lang.Object implements scalachat.remote.Event,java.io.Serializable,scala.ScalaObject,scala.Product
```

the companion object is not:

```
public final class scalachat.remote.Ping$ extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0 implements scala.ScalaObject
```

Now the question is: how can I specify that I want to use the class instead of the companion object? I also added an empty couple of parenthesis when I send the message as suggested by Aaron like in:

```
pong ! Ping()
```

but nothing is changed. In the end I also added a fake parameter to the case class

```
case class Ping(i: Int) extends Event
```

sending the message as:

```
pong ! Ping(0)
```

but without experiencing any difference still. Any suggestion?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need to explicitly implement `Serializable` interface, as both case classes and case objects are already implicitly use `@serializable` (it's just sugared out). Compile your code with `scalac -print` to see the stripped code - it may help you to figure out what's the problem. A small test in the REPL shows that case classes can be [de-]serialized against 2.8.0.

Comment: http://gist.github.com/657953

Comment: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/deprecate-serializable-td3002109.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@serializable case class Foo
```

I was also surprised that case objects were serializable per default.

Edit: After reading the exception properly I suspect that:

You're trying to send the generated companion object of the case class over the wire, instead of an instance of the case class.

Comment: Case classes are serializable by default too. Btw, in the snippets above case classes inherit from `Serializable`, which is in the most cases equal to using `@serializable` annotation

Comment: In general, it's not recommended to use `@serializable`, and it will probably be deprecated soon: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/deprecate-serializable-td3002109.html

Comment: Sorry, but I think you are not responding to my question. The @serializable annotation and extending the Serializable interface should be almost the same (even if the first one is apparently going to be deprecated) Anyway I also tried to use the @serializable annotation and I experienced the same effect: case object can be made serializable while case classes can't. In other words even to write @serializable case class Ping doesn't work in my example.

Comment: To clarify Viktor's edit, it looks like you're calling `writeObject(Ping)` instead of `writeObject(Ping())`.

Answer (score 4):

Case classes without parameters are meaningless and deprecated. And I see no `Serializable` in Scala, just `serializable`. Does it work if you fix these things?

Comment: I wanted to use case classes exactly because I needed to add some parameters to them. The Serializable interface is actually the one in java.io package and using the @serializable annotation does the same and gives the same issue I experienced. Moreover, for what I know the @serializable annotation is going to be deprecated and this is the only reason why I was avoiding to use it.

Comment: @Mario I mean extending scala.serializable, which is the recommended way of doing it.